# Can't resolve all paramaters for ContactEdit page

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to work with local storage, and i need to inject it into my constructor and when i do so, i get the following error

> 'Can't resolve all parameters for ContactEdit page ?, [object Object],
>   [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object].

this is how my constructor is setup:

```
 constructor(private storage: Storage,
public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private provider: ContactProvider, 
private toast: ToastController) {
```

I am unsure why am i getting this error, because im pretty sure i've done the imports correctly, this is how i did it:

app.module.ts

```
    import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

      imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
 ],
```

Comment: Can you show the page import statements? also I assume the page is lazy loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH6-SW1), [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) and [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197050(VS.85).aspx) documentation, the functionality seems to be limited to handle only string key/value pairs.

A workaround can be to [*stringify*](http://www.json.org/js.html) your object before storing it, and later parse it when you retrieve it:

```
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

Comment: Ah i undestand, but i can't even inject Storage into my constructor without it underlining my @IonicPage decorator in red and giving these errors, i dont think this would work

Comment: `localStorage` can be accessible from any where.